# django-autocomplete-light on fetch data

Tags: jquery, django, django-autocomplete-light

autocomplete-light.
Can any one help me. I want to show button 'add' if autocomplite return nothing (Object does not exists yet). Where can I check what get autocomplite from back-end.

Something like this

```
$('#myauto_field').yourlabsAutocomplete({
    fetch: function() { //Override fetch function
        //call fetch from jQuery
        //get data and see is it empty or note. If empty show button. 
    }
})
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in [test_project](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project/ajax_create) (which I just did for fun), try it in `/admin/ajax_create/creatable/add/`. It's maybe not the best way and maybe not **exactly** what you want, but it sure is a really good start. You can test it [here](http://jpic.pythonanywhere.com/admin/ajax_create/creatable/add/). You can easily adapt it to your exact specifications by bloating the javascript.

Instead, I'd recommend just using add-another.

Comment: ['here'](http://jpic.pythonanywhere.com/admin/ajax_create/creatable/add/) can't login with login: test, pass: test

Comment: Well I can login with test/test. Maybe you did it wrong ? Anyway, you could also [install the test_project in a temporary virtualenv locally](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/demo.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be this help's some one to save some time. My solution is:
Add 
`this.input.trigger('fetch', jqXHR);`
to autocomplite.js function yourlabs.Autocomplete.prototype.fetchComplete and put bind fetch for autocomplite input field

```
$('#' + fieldid).yourlabsAutocomplete({})
     .input.bind('fetch', function(e, replay){
           if(replay.responseText.indexOf("No matches found") == -1){
              //Here code if object not found
           }
});
```